# WordPress file permissions on CentOS7 requiring sudo

Tags: apache-2.4, wordpress, centos7, file-permissions, user-permissions

I'm running WordPress on my VPS with CentOS 7 LAMP stack.I've followed [this guide](http://www.stevejenkins.com/blog/2015/09/correct-permissions-for-wordpress/) to set permissions, i.e. I've run

`sudo chown apache:apache -R *` 
to ensure that my wordpress directory is owned by `apache:apache`.

I've also set WordPress directory and file permissions with these commands:

`find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

`find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

(I had to prefix the above commands with `sudo`)

Normally I manage the server by logging in through SSH using `myuser`, where `myuser` belongs to the `apache` group and the `wheel` group.

I have 3 problems:

1. Any file CRUD command in the WordPress directory still requires me to prefix the command with `sudo`, or else I get a permission error. Since `myuser` belongs to `apache` and `apache` owns the directory, I'm confused as to why I still need to prefix the commands with `sudo`.
2. Similar to problem 1, any `git` command such as a `git pull` requires me to prefix the command with `sudo` or else I get a permission error.
3. When I try to automatically update theme files from my WordPress dashboard web interface, I get permission errors. Interestingly, I'm able to install/update plugins via the WordPress dashboard without any permissions errors.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: Why have you made the files owned by apache?

Comment: @MichaelHampton according to [this guide](http://www.stevejenkins.com/blog/2015/09/correct-permissions-for-wordpress/), _WordPress works best if its files are “owned” by the same user that runs the web server. On Fedora/RedHat/CentOS platforms, the user’s simply apache._

Comment: That guide is crap. (Like so much of the Internet.) If you really want WordPress to be able to overwrite itself, my suggestion is [to use ACLs](http://serverfault.com/a/484819/126632).

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for the pointer I'll look into it. I'm still confused about Q1 though (why I still need to prefix commands with sudo). Any thoughts?

Comment: Because neither your user nor group is `apache`. You could have switched group to apache instead of switching user to root.

Comment: @MichaelHampton sorry I don't fully understand what's meant by "neither your user nor group is `apache`". I specifically set `myuser` to belong to the `apache` group; I thought this would give it the appropriate permissions? I'm new to linux permissions in general, thanks for the patience.