# Secure means of providing www-data and second user write access to www directory

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, ubuntu-16.04

On my `Ubuntu 16.04` server I had followed my provider's (Digital Ocean) suggestion to establish a new user (let's call them *user1*) and give them root privileges while being able to access remotely via `ssh`. I have a standard LAMP installation with the `imagemagick` library `php` installed.

`imagemagick` complained about being unable to write and I realised it was using the default apache user *www-data*, which had no write privileges, of which only *user1* had. So I chown'd the `www` directory to the *www-data user* and *www-data* group. I then added *user1* to the *www-data* group.

Thinking I would just chmod the directory and its contents to 775, I read more than one piece of advice suggesting that this is not very secure. Is there a recommended procedure for allowing *user1* write access to the directory; should I give `imagemagick` write permission by different means, or should I be using *www-var* for all file writing in this directory? I primarily sftp in for development and maintenance.

---

**Update**

It occurred to me that the only directory I need *www-data* to be able to write to can be isolated quite easily. So I executed `chown` on `www` and all its subdirs to *user1:www-data* instead, then ran `chmod` on the single folder and all its contents to 775. It only contains jpegs so this may be less of a vulnerability.

Comment: The permissions you've set up with your update are pretty standard, only allowing the httpd to write where you wish. Be sure to limit access to writing .htaccess and .htpasswd files or disable them.

Comment: Have you considered using [ACLs](http://serverfault.com/a/484819/126632) for this?