# How to allow nginx to write to a folder owned not by www-data

Tags: nginx, permissions, file-permissions

On Debian 8: I used "ChrootDirectory" to jail a user `fileuploader` to upload files to `/var/www/public` now the uploaded files and folders have the ownership `fileuploader:fileuploader`.

Now I serve these with nginx which uses the `www-data` user. I added user `www-data` to the `fileuploader` group. Serving is fine but nginx is not able to create files (For example Automatic update in Wordpress does not work). (Even when I do `chmod g+rwx` for the whole directory). It works when I change ownership of the folder to `www-data` but I would like to avoid that.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please edit into your answer the details about the distribution, because it tells whether you have AppArmor or SELinux.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/484819/126632